# How to preserve sessionID after browser close?

Tags: php, cookies

This is my php code.

```
<?php  
 session_start();
 print_r($_COOKIE);
?>
```

**I got**

```
Array ( [PHPSESSID] => vgojsl5kuuau35kpigsc5mepa3 )
```

When I closed by browser and hit my php file again. I got.

```
Array ( [PHPSESSID] => r0qaqm2h9o1oj5p70gpgi8k0c7 )
```

I want to save session Id in cookies. So, that when I closed the browser and  hit the file again I should get  same session id every time on hit, until cookies clear by user.

Comment: Why do you want the same session ID?

Comment: @James I just want to do that.I am trying , Is it possible?

Comment: There are ways, but I'm thinking you're trying to do something the wrong way, or long way around as this is not usually required for most code requirements (if it is, you'll likely be doing something special and know how to do this anyway). What is the ultimate goal? Why do you want to keep the same session ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sessions are not meant to behave that way. Every time you close the browser, Sessions get destroyed. What you need is to set cookies.

Cookies...

```
<?php
if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookiename']))
{
setcookie('cookiename','cookievalue',time()+3600);// This cookie lives for an hour
}
else
{
echo "Welcome ".$_COOKIE['cookiename'];
}
```

Comment: But how can I do so in cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you've saved it before; if not: save it now with the current PHPSESSID.

```
if(!$_COOKIE["SAVED_PHPSESSID"]) {
    setcookie("SAVED_PHPSESSID", $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"], time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there’s an error in Shankar Damodaran’s answer. The second line should be changed from

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookiename'])) to if(!isset($_COOKIE['cookiename']))
```

Alternatively, the fourth and eighth lines should swap places.

**Update:** Shankar Damodaran has already changed the second line. Now his answer is perfect.